# How do I "force" surround sound in audio properties of Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, audio, surround-sound, creative

I am running Windows 7 Professional on the 15" MacBook Pro Retina.

I have the [Creative Sound Blaster X-Fi Go! Pro](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0044DEDC0), which is a USB sound card, and I enabled THX TruStudio Pro to enable virtual surround sound. I have a headphone connecting to the USB sound card.

In some games, I have the option to select 7.1 speakers, but some games detect from the Windows sound properties whether to encode in surround sound.

Is there a way to "force" or "trick" Windows into thinking it has surround speakers? Notice that I can't select "Surround speakers" in the image below:

[image]